# How to use c++ unique_ptr with the map container?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use the `unique_ptr` with the map container? For example,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    unique_ptr<map<string, int>> person;
    person = make_unique<map<string, int>>(make_pair("Tom", 34));

    cout << (*person)["Tom"] << endl;  
}
```

Comment: `person = make_unique<map<string, int>>(map<string, int>{ { "Tom", 34 } });` would work, and will use move semantics to make it relatively efficient.

Comment: Unrelated to your question. But why do you want to use `unique_ptr<map<string, int>>` instead of `map<string, int>`? Moving a `std::map` won't be more expensive than moving a `unique_ptr`. There are only rare cases where `unique_ptr<map<string, int>>` could be usefull.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What problems did you have? Does this code work? If not, _how_ not?

Answer (score 2):

How about defining:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unique_ptr<map<string, int>> person(new map<string, int>); 
    (*person)["Tom"] = 34;

    cout << (*person)["Tom"] << endl;  
}
```

Output is:

```
34
```

See for yourself: https://wandbox.org/permlink/CNaWMLYJTxQSfKwt .

Comment: And what is the benefit over writing `unique_ptr<map<string, int>> person = make_unique<map<string, int>>(); (*person)["Tom"] = 34;`? Why do you suggest an additional `map` in your solution?

Comment: Wait, doesn't it just create an additional COPY of the map for no reason?

Comment: @t.niese what you wrote there is very neat. I suggested an additional `map` in my code to answer the OP question, to show it possible to attach a `map` to a `unique_pointer`.

Comment: `to show it possible to attach a map to a unique_pointer` no, it creates a copy of `my_map` that is stored in the `map` created by `make_unique<map<string, int>>(… )`. If you write `my_map["Tom"] = 35;` after the `unique_ptr<map<string, int>> person = make_unique<map<string, int>>(my_map);` the output will still be `34`.

Comment: @t.niese I am quite tired today, so much so that in writing my answer I have glossed over these very fine points you make. I have modified my very flawed answer accordingly.

Comment: @John Cvelth I have now addressed all that vile nonsense I wrote before.

Comment: @Lingo yep, good job. But, if I were nitpicking, I'd still prefer `std::make_unique`, as it looks better than a naked `new`, as well as using it to set the initial value.

Comment: @John Cvelth Points of view, my friend, points of view. Beauty lies in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @Lingo Can't say I disagree :)